# One to many relationship in Entity core deleting the previous records in child table as part of parent-child update

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have 3 entities like Book, Author, and BookAuthor(junction table), I have master data for Author and one book can have multiple Authors, so BookAuthor will store the BookId and AuthorId.

Here, the issue is I have created book records with 2 authors initially, so it saved the one record into the Book table and 2 records into BookAuthor table. In the next request, I have added one more author, expectation is it should insert one more record into the BookAuthor table and it should contain 3 records.
But what is happening is as part of the update it is deleting the previous two records and Inserting the new record into the BookAuthor table.

Book.cs

```
    private string _name;
    private int _pageCount;
    private List<BookAuthor> _bookAuthors = new List<BookAuthor>();

    public Book()
    {
            
    }

    public Book(string name, int pageCount)
    {
        _name = name;
        _pageCount = pageCount;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name => _name;
    public int PageCount => _pageCount;

    public IEnumerable<BookAuthor> BookAuthors => _bookAuthors;
```

Author.cs

```
    private string _name;
    private int _age;
    private List<BookAuthor> _bookAuthors = new List<BookAuthor>();

    public Author()
    {

    }

    public Author(string name, int age)
    {
        _name = name;
        _age = age;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name => _name;
    public int Age => _age;

    public IEnumerable<BookAuthor> BookAuthors => _bookAuthors;
```

BookAuthor.cs

```
    private int _bookId;
    private int _authorId;

    private Book _book;
    private Author _author;

    public BookAuthor()
    {

    }

    public BookAuthor(int bookId, int authorId)
    {
        _bookId = bookId;
        _authorId = authorId;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BookId => _bookId;
    public int AuthorId => _authorId;

    public Book Book => _book;
    public Author Author => _author;
```

Using the above created the Entity configuration.

```
 public class AuthorConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Author>
   {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Author> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.Property(b => b.Name).HasField("_name");
        builder.Property(b => b.Age).HasField("_age");
        builder.HasMany(t => t.BookAuthors).WithOne(t => 
         t.Author).HasForeignKey(t => t.AuthorId);
  builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Book.BookAuthors)).SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}


  
  public class BookConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Book>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Book> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.Property(b => b.Name).HasField("_name");
        builder.Property(b => b.PageCount).HasField("_pageCount");
        builder.HasMany(t => t.BookAuthors).WithOne(t => t.Book).HasForeignKey(t => t.BookId);

        builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Book.BookAuthors)).SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }
}


  public class BookAuthorConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<BookAuthor>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BookAuthor> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(b => b.Id);
        builder.Property(b => b.BookId).HasField("_bookId");
        builder.Property(b => b.AuthorId).HasField("_authorId");
        builder.HasOne(a => a.Book).WithMany(a => a.BookAuthors).HasForeignKey(a => a.BookId);
        builder.HasOne(a => a.Author).WithMany(a => a.BookAuthors).HasForeignKey(a => a.AuthorId);
    }
}
```

Update Code

```
  public async Task<Result> UpdateReference(BookDto bookDto)
    {
        var bookresult = await _bookRepository.GetById(bookDto.Id);
        bookresult.Value.Update(bookDto.Name, bookDto.PageCount, bookDto.AuthorIds);

        var result = await _bookRepository.Update(bookresult.Value);
        if (!result.IsSucceeded)
            return Result.Fail(result.GetErrorString());

        return Result.Ok();

    }

    public void Update(string name, int pageCount, List<int> authersId)
    {
        _name = name;
        _pageCount = pageCount;
        UpdateAutherId(authersId);
    }

    private void UpdateAutherId(List<int> authersId)
    {
        if (authersId.Any())
        {
            var bookAuthors = GetBookAuthors(authersId);
            var newBookAuthors = bookAuthors.Except(_bookAuthors).ToList();
            var deletedBookAuthors = _bookAuthors.Except(bookAuthors).ToList();
            if (newBookAuthors.Any())
            {
                _bookAuthors.AddRange(newBookAuthors);
            }
            if (deletedBookAuthors.Any())
            {
                foreach (var bookAuthor in deletedBookAuthors)
                {
                    _bookAuthors.Remove(bookAuthor);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _bookAuthors.RemoveRange(0, _bookAuthors.Count);
        }
    }

   public override async Task<Result<Book>> GetById(int id)
    {
        var result = await _bookAuthorContext.Books
            .Include(a => a.BookAuthors)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(a => a.Id == id);

        if (result == null)
            return Result.Fail<Book>("no Data found", ApplicationResponseCode.BadRequest, ApplicationResponseCode.BadRequest);

        return Result.Ok<Book>(result);
    }
```

Comment: Could you post your update code please?

Comment: *"In the next request, I have added one more author"* How? Show that code because the problem is there (assuming the model and relationships are correctly mapped, which with this (redundant) style of declaring properties won't happen automatically).

Comment: If you want the configuration I can post here

Comment: updated the configuration and update code

Comment: There is still some unknown custom code in the repository method which hides what's going on exactly, but looks like your `UpdateAutherId(List<int> authersId)` method is deleting the existing links. Note that `_bookAuthors` won't be loaded automatically from the database if the repository method does not use `Include`. Also does `List<int> authersId` contains all ids or just the added one? You are the only one who can debug that.

Comment: I have included the bookauthores while fetching from DB while calling GetById, added the getByUd code, and also UpdateAutherId(List<int> authersId)  not deleting the existing records, if anything new added it will add, if anything deleted from previous list it will delete from that

Comment: @Ravikumar please consider marking my answer as helpful if it helped

Comment: I have already included BookAuthor object in the get

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is because you don't fetch the BookAuthor entities when you retrieve specific book from DB.
You can rely on EF here and simply retrieve the `Book` entity from db but don't forget to `Include` the `BookAuthor` entities.
Then all you need to call is simply replace existing `BookAuthor` collection with another one and after saving the changes, EF will perform inserts/deletes automatically

```
var myBook = db.Books.Include(b => b.BookAuthors).SingleOrDefalut(b => b == ...);
myBook.BookAuthors = newBookAuthors;
db.SaveChanges();
```